# Android Studio 3.0 Compile Issue (Cannot choose between Configurations)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, project

Issue with latest 3.0 build (Beta 2)
My project has 1 sub module by a 3rd party so I only have access to their build.gradle.

My project has 3 flavours, snap, uat, production. Each has 2 build types, debug and release. When I try build I get this.

```
Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :lp_messaging_sdk:
  - debugApiElements
  - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseApiElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
```

I read there was issues with sub modules and build types but then read it was fixed.
You had to add the same build types or something to the sub modules build.gradle and then add

```
buildTypeMatching  'debug', 'release'
```

When I do this however, I get this error,

```
Error:Could not select value from candidates [debug, release] using AlternateDisambiguationRule.BuildTypeRule.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':lp_messaging_sdk').file('aars')
        }
    }

    // Android parameters
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.1'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        versionName buildName
        versionCode buildVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en", "fr", "fr-rCA"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        snap {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "INTERNAL"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = 'changelog.txt'
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
            dimension "default"
        }

        uat {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "INTERNAL"
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
        }

        production {
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix createVersionNameSuffix()
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME", '"' + PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME + '"'
            // Workaround for : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212882
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

        release {
            versionNameSuffix createVersionNameSuffix()
            minifyEnabled true
            testCoverageEnabled = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME", '"' + PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME + '"'
            // Workaround for : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212882
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()
        }

    }

    //Used to ignore duplicated entries added to meta-inf
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
        dexInProcess true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        xmlReport true
        htmlReport true
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'InvalidPackage'
        disable 'GradleCompatible', 'GradleCompatible'
        disable 'NewApi', 'NewApi'
        disable 'GradleDependency'
        disable 'UnusedResources'
        disable 'IconDensities'
        disable 'TypographyDashes'
        disable 'ContentDescription'
        htmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.html")
        xmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.xml")
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 13
    targetGenDir 'src/main/java/'
}

ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = System.getenv("CHANGELOG")

def createVersionNameSuffix() {
    def buildNumber = System.env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def buildTimestamp = new Date().format('HH:mm dd/MM/yy')
    return buildNumber ? " ($buildNumber)" : " ($buildTimestamp)"
}

def getBuildVersionFromName(String buildName) {
    List data = buildName.tokenize(".")
    String resultString = "19";

    for (String s : data) {
        resultString += s;
    }

    if (System.env.BUILD_NUMBER) {
        resultString += System.env.BUILD_NUMBER
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(resultString);
}

//Verify the app before creating a Pull Request
task verifyPR
verifyPR.dependsOn('clean')
verifyPR.dependsOn('lint')
verifyPR.dependsOn('checkstyle')
verifyPR.dependsOn('pmd')
verifyPR.dependsOn('testSnapDebugUnitTest')

dependencies {
    // Android Dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    // Dagger Dependencies
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'

    // Rx Dependencies
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.whorlwind:whorlwind:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'
    compile 'com.jenzz:RxAppState:2.0.0'

    // Tools
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5'

    // ButterKnife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

    // Google Maps
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'

    // Geofence
    compile('pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'

    // OKHTTP
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'

    // Libphonenumber
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.2'

    // UI
    compile 'com.tubb.smrv:swipemenu-recyclerview:5.0.2'

    // EventBus
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    // Database
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'

    // Chuck HTTP Inspector
    debugCompile 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.0.4'
    releaseCompile 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.0.4'

    // ViewPager Indicator
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'

    // Amplitude
    compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.13.2'

    // TESTS
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4"

    compile project(':lp_messaging_sdk')
}
```

And here is the 3rd party library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 250
        versionName "2.5.0"
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        snap {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "INTERNAL"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = 'changelog.txt'
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
            dimension "default"
        }

        uat {
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "INTERNAL"
            ext.betaDistributionNotifications = true
        }

        production {

        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

    buildTypeMatching 'snap', 'debug', 'release'

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            buildConfigField "String", "PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME", '"' + PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME + '"'
            // Workaround for : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212882
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            testCoverageEnabled = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME", '"' + PLAY_STORE_VERSION_NAME + '"'
            // Workaround for : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212882
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }

    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.31'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'

    compile(name: 'infra', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'messaging', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'messaging_ui', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'ui', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue? 
Thanks

Comment: can you provide your app gradle ?

Comment: @ibrahim Hi I provided the build.gradle

Comment: *All flavors* need to specify at least one dimension. Post build.gradle of the library so we can check it as well.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I posted it above, thanks

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try

`implementation project(path: ':lp_messaging_sdk', configuration: 'default')`

### ***Note:***

**You can avoid this bug by update gradle to `4.3` [check this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3009).**

**Explanation** :

Using [Dependency Configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations) makes it easy to define and specify what to use in sub-project.

In my answer, we used **default** configuration and this will publish and expose only the "release" flavor to other Android projects and modules.

Assume you need to include this flavor only with demo flavor or with release flavor, [it would be like](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:configurations) :

```
configurations {
  // Initializes placeholder configurations that the Android plugin can use when targeting
  // the corresponding variant of the app.
  demoDebugCompile {}
  fullReleaseCompile {}
  ...
}
dependencies {
  // If the library configures multiple build variants using product flavors,
  // you must target one of the library's variants using its full configuration name.
  demoDebugCompile project(path: ':lp_messaging_sdk', configuration: 'demoDebug')
  fullReleaseCompile project(path: ':lp_messaging_sdk', configuration: 'fullRelease')
  ...
}
```

And so, in your case, you may use your build flavors, and that's what appeared in the error log.

```
Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :lp_messaging_sdk
```

And that's mean, that your `lp_messaging_sdk` have various build configurations:-

```
  - debugApiElements
  - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseApiElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
```

And android-studio telling you, that "I can't choose one configuration from these various, Would you define one for me?"

You can read more over [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#publish_multiple_variants).

Comment: @goodgamerguy you welcome, i updated answer with demonstrate it.

Comment: I had to use:
`compile project(path: ':module', configuration: 'default')`

Comment: I have to clean and rebuild the project, but then it works. Thanks!

Comment: `implementation project(path: ':lp_messaging_sdk', configuration: 'default')` that is not allow now, instead use this `implementation project( ':lp_messaging_sdk')`

Answer (score 13):

Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project.......

There may be gradle writing problems
When I changed to the following wording there is no such error

//    compile project(':MPChartLib')

```
implementation project(':MPChartLib')
```

Maybe when the reference depends on other modules should be written in this implementation

Comment: Is there anything you can add to your answer to help others decipher it's meaning?

Comment: and I use the gradle version "4.1" and "4.3" , Can not solve this problem, In addition to changing this wording. 
but it has  a new problem
Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

Comment: See "Migrate dependency configurations for local modules" in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the android-apt plugin for annotation processing, try removing that plugin and replacing all of the `apt some_dependency` references with `annotationProcessor some_dependency` as suggested in [the migration guide for the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config).

Comment: Awesome solution thanks ! replaces kapt project(:processor) with annotationProcessor project(:processor)

Answer (score 4):

for AndroidStudio 3.0+,  mainMoudle has buildTypes and buildTypes as same as libModule  buildTypes and buildTypes  ,it would like:

mainModule:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG", "false"
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_DEBUG", "true"
        zipAlignEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug2{

    }
}
```

libModule:

```
buildTypes {
    release {

    }

    debug {

    }

    debug2{

    }
}
```

or you can use matchingFallbacks solve this [click](https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration)

Answer (score 3):

When I updated my project from API level 23 to 27 and Gradle to 3.1 this error comes that

> Can not choose between different configuration

So to solve this problem.

replace the

```
compile project(':your projectName')
```

with

```
implementation project(':projectname')
```

in Gradle, this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my, similar, case the solution was:

*build.gradle:*

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // because I have two project flavors in that library
        missingDimensionStrategy 'project', 'myProjectName' 
        // because I have a "full" and a "debug" flavor in that library
        missingDimensionStrategy 'mode', 'full'
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug { ... }
        release { ... }
    }
}
dependencies {
    // because the project(path:'', configuration:'') did not work in this case
    implementation project(':myModuleName1')
    implementation project(':myModuleName2')
}
```

Maybe this helps others ending up here with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, run into the same error on Android Studio 3.5.2, with a different cause. I was trying to add an application module as a library.

I resolved it by simply [converting the application module to a library module](https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/projects/android-library.html#Convert) .

Answer (score 1):

This error is also due to if the following is NOT true:

#### By including a module B in A, all the producFlavors that exist in A have to exist in B.

---

### build.gradle (:app) or (:module-A)

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "dimen"
    productFlavors {
        someProduct {
            dimension "dimen"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(path: ':module-B')
}
```

So `someProduct` has to exist in B

### build.gradle (:module-B)

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "dimen"
    productFlavors {
        someProduct {
            dimension "dimen"
        }
    }
}
```

GL

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the fact that I was renaming the output file name(and path)

Once I've removed the gradle code that was changing the name of the aar the road to my solution was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the complex setup where there is a module and than there are some submodules etc. Than you need to add the build variants to the module(say top module) and than to submodule and other modules that might be using your module. You can not directly add to submodule or else android studio will get confused as to which one to pick.

**Just to give an Example, let us say there is snapDebug for submodule as build variant, now it should be clubbed with a snapDebug for Top Module or snapDebug of a module using it. If snapDebug  is not there in either of them, android studio will get confused which one to pick with the one of other one. Hence the error in latest builds of android studio.**

Hope it helps to understand the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, when your main project uses modules or library modules(AAR) that have flavor dimensions, your app doesn't know which one to use. You should Use **missingDimensionStrategy** in the **defaultConfig** block of your app's build.gradle file to specify the default flavor. For example :

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'dimension', 'flavor1', 'flavor2'
```

Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors) link for more details.