# Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta - Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After migrating to android gradle plugin "3.0.0-beta7" i added my application module. Since 3.0.0 buildTypes should be the same in MAIN MODULE and dependency MODULE. I did dat but i'm still getting these errors:

```
"Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve project :library"
```

This error is repeated for all variants: debug, tst and release. I already read the whole [migrate to 3.0 tutorial by android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html). Also tried adding `matchingFallbacks` even though buildTypes are exactly the same but keep receiving these errors. Seems like there is a bug in the plugin or something..

build.gradle app module:

```
 signingConfigs {
    tstRelease {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            matchingFallbacks 'debug'
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            testCoverageEnabled !project.hasProperty('android.injected.invoked.from.ide')
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
        tst {

            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.tstRelease
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            //TODO: add more proguard configs here for different libs
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.tstRelease
        }
        flavorDimensions "default"

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += "src/test-common/java"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/test-common/java"
    }
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig rootProject.file('lint.xml')
    }
}
```

How i invoke my `library:

```
implementation project(path: ":library" )
```

build.gradle :library module:

`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildTypes {
    debug {

    }
    tst {

    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.prodConfig
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", ""
    }

}

play {
    jsonFile = file(serviceAccountName)
    track = 'alpha'
}

flatc {
    genMutable = true
}
```

:library module - dependencies
    /// FCM; Crash Reporting; Notification; Remote config
    dependencies {

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${rootProject.ext.daggerVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${rootProject.ext.daggerVersion}"

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${rootProject.ext.timberVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.agera:agera:${rootProject.ext.ageraVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.agera:content:${rootProject.ext.ageraVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.agera:database:${rootProject.ext.ageraVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.agera:net:${rootProject.ext.ageraVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.android.agera:rvadapter:${rootProject.ext.ageraVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"

    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${rootProject.ext.gsonVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${rootProject.ext.okHttpVersion}"

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    api project(":androidtestlib")


    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:${rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion}"

    implementation "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:${rootProject.ext.jobDispatcherVersion}"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.47'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.12.3'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

EDIT:

adding

```
api project(path: ":library", configuration: 'default' )
```

or

```
implementation project(path: ":library", configuration: 'default' )
```

Results in the project compiling but when trying to use classes of module the following popup appears.

[image]

Here i can choose to add dependency to project. Which results in Android studio adding the dependency the <3 android gradle plugin way. Which gives me the same errors as stated on top of the question.

Comment: You could try 3.0.0-rc1

Comment: can you show your app.gradle dependency ?

Comment: @Ibrahim what do you mean, :library dependency is already in question :)

Comment: @SjaakRusma i mean how you invoke this library in app dependency ?

Comment: @Ibrahim i think i know what u mean, added it!

Comment: @SjaakRusma related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685318/6490462

Comment: @Ibrahim this makes the app compile but i'm unable to import a class from that module. On Alt + Enter it will ask to add dependency ':library' to app project and then you have the same circus. For somehow `configuration: default` just includes nothing..

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira updated to rc1! issue persists unfortunately

Comment: @SjaakRusma use `api` instead of implementation

Comment: @SjaakRusma worked, or still facing issues ?

Comment: Do you have this project "library", right?

Comment: Since it's worked after define configuration path, so i think it's a duplicate question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 Compile Issue (Cannot choose between Configurations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679847/android-studio-3-0-compile-issue-cannot-choose-between-configurations)

Comment: @Leandro Borges Ferreira yes called it library due to confidentiality

Comment: @SjaakRusma show your library dependencies.

Comment: @Ibrahim added dependencies. btw the :library module is an application module