# ANDROID STUDIO 3.0 upgrade : Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:xxxxxxxDebugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I found this warning after upgrading the latest android studio stable version

**Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:xxxxxxxDebugCompileClasspath'.**

> Failed to transform file 'commons-lang-2.4.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
>   Transform output file xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/app/commons-lang-2.4.jar does not exist.

here is gradle and gradle wrapper versions :

**gradle** : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

and

**gradle wrapper** :

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/g‌​radle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: what's the gradle plugin version and the gradle wrapper version ??

Comment: gradle :         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
gradle wrapper : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: could you post your gradle file. for both module and project level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 Compile Issue (Cannot choose between Configurations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679847/android-studio-3-0-compile-issue-cannot-choose-between-configurations)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

change dependency declaration

from

**`compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.4.jar')`**

to

**`implementation files('libs/commons-lang-2.4.jar')`**

Comment: @Kenji can you explain it better : I think it is another case

Comment: For me, the jar file was built from NDK sources.  It was solved by a combination of adding 'implementation' in place of 'compile', but also making sure that the paths to the jar file were correct in all cases.

Comment: My case does not have dependencies complie files, but classpath instead

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, build -> clean project worked for me.

Comment: thx @DDeex, worked for me as well, upvoted for saving my day.

Answer (score 3):

Change the classpath of Project Gradle to:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
```

OR

change distributionUrl of gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem , googled a lot but nothing worked. Following worked for me on Android 4.2.1

> Go to File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore IDE Settings

Then follow the instructions.