# Unable to resolve local library dependency on android studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

When compiling with latest Android Studio 3.0 (gradle 4.1) I get

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@fullReleasenoproguard/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aFileChooser.

I fixed it changing in `build.gradle` from

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':aFileChooser', configuration: 'default')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952796/android-studio-3-0-upgrade-errorcould-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez different scope, this refers to local library include. I spent quite some time figuring out that adding `configuration: 'default'` made it possible to use old local libraries

Comment: did you try with dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':aFileChooser')
}

Comment: Yes but it didn't work. Seems like the additional configuration part is required for old libraries

Comment: Could you please provide gradle file of app and aFileChooser then i can surely help you :)

Comment: @Newbie the aFileChoose gradle file is pretty standard:
   
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    }