# I keep getting this error when i try to run a build on android studio

Tags: java

I keep getting this error when i try to run a build on android studio

```
C:\Users\Elvis\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dd431bf221ce9c2f6297da7fd76f4b41\aapt2-3.5.2-5435860-windows

org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.iterator(CompositeFileCollection.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:59)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:83)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.registerAaptService(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.getResourceProcessor(MergeResources.java:172)
```

Comment: That's not an error you posted, it is just a windows file path.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952796/android-studio-3-0-upgrade-errorcould-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration help? If not, please review [ask], then [edit] your question and add a [mcve].