# How to fix "Variant selection conflict found"?

Tags: android

In my project I have a few modules. If `Build Variant` tab all in debug build variant all is ok

[image]

But if I change one of the module to `release` build variant his dependency modules also change to `release`, but with kind of error

[image]

I tried this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011770/5709159

for me it doesn't work

How to fix it?

Comment: Does it work if you change the `app` project to release as well? I'm going on a wild assumption that the `app` module also depends on the libraries and conflicts when it's dependencies have the wrong variant

Comment: @JensV hmm, yes, you are right it is works... So, I does it mean that it is normal behavior?

Comment: I'd presume so... In theory, building `president_app` should still work even with the error. But if you try to build `app` it will fail because the dependencies have the wrong variant. You'd have to test it, I'm not sure if I'm right. If that's the case, it's more like a warning than an error

Comment: @JensV yes, you are right, it is works. It is really looks like a warning

Answer (score 4):

Hover over the red area you can see the reason:

> Module 'XXX' has variant 'release' selected, but the module "XXX"
> depends on variant 'debug'

It's because the dependent modules are using the wrong building variant.

Comment: For me just shows "Fix Problem" :(